# Display a list of posts corresponding to a category

Tags: php, categories

I have this code that is displaying a list of my blogposts on my index.
What I would like is to add a category parameter to it, to only display a list of the posts with a specific category.
I don't seem to be able to do it, without breaking everything...

Thanks for your precious help.

```
    <?php $all_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

if ( $all_posts->have_posts() ):?>

    <ul>
        <?php while ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) : $all_posts->the_post();  global $post;
            ?>

            <li class='sub-menu'> 
                <a href='#' class="exposition"  data-id="<?php the_id();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php $images = get_field('gallery');?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Here are some category parameters from the docs which may help https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters

Comment: I know how to add a query, but I don't know how to check it then.
`$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'test' )`
then there is the if but I don't know how to check `if = 'test'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, consider using get_posts()?

[get_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/)

It will require other changes to your code but you can easily create a query to include Categories, and then foreach through the results.

**Update:**
Here's an equivalent to your code written with get_posts(). Take a copy of your own code first but the below would replace it all. Note the Category ID in the arguments - this is what you need to change to suit your needs.

get_posts() is a much simpler function for this kind of use case than WP_Query but is less flexible if you want complex queries.

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'category' => 1 //REPLACE THIS NUMBER WITH YOUR CATEGORY ID!
);

$all_posts = get_posts( $args );

if (count($all_posts) > 0) : ?>

<ul>
<?php 
    foreach ( $all_posts as $post ) : ?>
        <li class="sub-menu"> 
            <a href='#' class="exposition"  data-id="<?php _e($post->ID);?>">
                <?php _e($post->post_title);?>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <?php _e($post->post_content);?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        
        <?php 
    endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have no clue on how to do that...

Comment: I've updated my answer with some sample code for you.

Comment: thanks a lot, works perfectly fine! :)